# IPFS in Javascript 'cat' function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ipfs

I created this testcase to prove that the cat method is not working for me using the IPFS javascript library.  What am I doing wrong ?  My console output does not draw anything from within the 'node.files.cat' function, its as if that (err,filestream) callback is not being called at all.  I I know my multihash is somewhat working because if I change it I get a fatal error.  However right now it is seemingly just locking up and pausing after NODE READY.

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const path = require('path')
const os = require('os')
const fs = require('fs')

console.log('ipfs test ')


var mhash = "Qmc5LfkMVAhvzip2u2RjRBRhgVthtSokHsz4Y5bgaBCW2R";


// Create the IPFS node instance
const node = new IPFS()

node.on('ready', () => {

  // Your node is now ready to use \o/


    console.log('NODE READY')



/*
THIS WORKS
    var test_rstream = fs.createReadStream( path.join(__dirname, '.', '/public/sample_land_file.json') )
    var wstream =  fs.createWriteStream(os.tmpdir() + '/lobc_cache/'+'Qmc5LfkMVAhvzip2u2RjRBRhgVthtSokHsz4Y5bgaBCW2R');


      wstream.on('finish', function() {
       console.log('Written ' + wstream.bytesWritten + ' ' + wstream.path);
         test_rstream.close()
      });

       test_rstream.pipe(wstream);

*/


    node.files.cat("Qmc5LfkMVAhvzip2u2RjRBRhgVthtSokHsz4Y5bgaBCW2R", function (err, filestream) {

          console.log('WHY ISNT THIS FIRING ') // i never see this logged
        console.log(filestream)

        console.log(os.tmpdir())


        if (!fs.existsSync(os.tmpdir() + '/lobc_cache')){
          fs.mkdirSync(os.tmpdir() + '/lobc_cache');
        }

        var wstream =  fs.createWriteStream(os.tmpdir() + '/lobc_cache/'+'Qmc5LfkMVAhvzip2u2RjRBRhgVthtSokHsz4Y5bgaBCW2R');



        result   = '';


          wstream.on('finish', function() {
           console.log('Written ' + wstream.bytesWritten + ' ' + wstream.path);
             filestream.close()
          });


                filestream.pipe(wstream);

              //  wstream.end();
  // file will be a stream containing the data of the file requested
    })





  // stopping a node
  node.stop(() => {
    // node is now 'offline'
  })
})


node.on('start', () => {

  console.log('NODE START')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. A quick way to solve it is just to put the node.files.cat inside the callback for .on('ready'). Seems that bitswap is dropping requests before the node is *online*.

Let me know if this works.